# Does a USA company that does business with a European Union country like the Czech Republic pay Vat on services rendered

Tags: vat

Should an EU based country like the Chzech Republic charge VAT to services rendered to a USA based company?  These would be IT related services.

An example would be DBA work, let's say charged at $20 USD / hour, if they worked 10 hours would the invoice be $200 in total or $200 + VAT (21%)?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a *personal* finance question. What makes you think the company should *not* charge VAT?

Comment: I see a lot of vat questions here but am happy to remove it. I have no idea how vat works which is why i asked it.